# What can we say about convergence of pairwise independent random variables?

Tags: probability-theory

A standard corollary of Kolmogorov`s $0$-$1$-Law is that the series $S_{n}:=X_{1}+...+X_{n}$ of independent random variables $(X_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges with probability $\in \{0,1\}$.

Does this still hold if we replace independence by pairwise independence of the random variables? I have tried to find a counterexample, but failed.